# Left join taking longer time to execute

Tags: sql, join, hive, hiveql

I have an issue, have 2 tables (temporary) A & B, A has 127 rows and B has around 2874561 rows.

Trying

```
SELECT A.COL1, B.COL2 
FROM A LEFT JOIN B 
WHERE A.DATE BETWEEN B.ALLOW_D AND B.SEL_D
```

and it's taking a lot of time to execute and running on mr.

Tried with Tez, MAPJOIN, STREAMTABLE also ...

```
set mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize=71582788;
set mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize=71582788;
```

but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is your `LEFT JOIN` actually works as `cross` if it is without `ON` condition, it duplicates rows B x A, `2874561x127 = 365M`, producing too many rows, then `WHERE` filters only rows satisfying condition: `A.DATE BETWEEN B.ALLOW_D AND B.SEL_D`.

Try to reduce the number of rows in right table. Say if you know that in table A the minimum date is 2018-01-01, use it as a filter for table B (use subquery before join with `WHERE B.ALLOW_D>='2018-01-01'`). Ideally if you can replace `BETWEEN` with equality join `ON` condition. Aggregation and Filtering before join can be cheaper than cross join + filtering.

Try to load incrementally and reduce the number of rows before join.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. The Table B is bit complex Temporary table with union of many tables like select 1.allow_d,1.sel_d,1.col1 from 1 union all 2.allow_d,2.sel_d,2.col2 from 2 union all 3.allow_d,3.sel_d,3.col3 from 3 union all 4.allow_d,4.sel_d,4.col4 from 4... I dont' know on condition I need filter this... may be like max 0r min function ? Could you share some example , how can I filter this temp table so that I can use between clause when joined with A table?.. Kindly help...

Comment: @Ma28 Yes. as a first step select min(A.DATE) as min_dt and max(A.DATE) , max_dt date from the main (left) table. Now you can use these values to filter your right table like (select * from b where B.ALLOW_D>= min_dt  and B.SEL_D <= max_dt ) as tableB and use this subquery in the same join instead of table B. It's just a guess. Maybe will not help much, depends on your data. If you are lucky you may reduce the table to fit in mapjoin

Comment: But IMHO something is very wrong with architecture. non-equality joins are not good for Hive. Joins without ON (cross) with big tables are the worst you can do. Think how to redesign architecture so, you will eliminate this join at all.

Comment: And join without ON is CROSS. Use CROSS JOIN. to understand better what the code is actually does